# TikZ 3D plot : how to add spaces between tick labels to prevent them from colliding?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, ticks

I have a 3D plot with colliding `yticklabels`, which I have been unable to fix for now. Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath}
%
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %graphique        
        \begin{axis}[
            width=4 cm,
            height=4 cm,
            xmin=3,xmax=6,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.023,
            zmin=1,zmax=1.8,
            xlabel=x,
            ylabel=y,
            zlabel=z,
            zticklabel style = {yshift=0.1cm}, %to prevent it from colliding with xlabels
            xtick = {3,4,5,6},
            ytick ={0.006,0.012,0.017,0.023},
            yticklabels = {0.6,1.2,1.7,2.3},
            ztick ={1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8},
            scaled y ticks = false,
            view           = {30}{30},
            ]  
            
            \addplot3[fill=black!15,opacity=0.35,thick] (4,0,1) -- (4,0.023,1) -- (4,0.023,1.8) -- (4,0,1.8) -- cycle;
            
        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Giving for now:

[image: minimum working example initial result, with yticklabels colliding]

Would you know a way to relax the `yticklabel` so that they do not collide ? The only solution I found so far was to delete it in the axis by passing `yticklabels = {,,,}`, only to define it manually after the `\end{axis}`...

Thank you for your time!

PS: the axis width, height, view and the font size must not be changed ;)

Comment: your image is small, so there is not enough space for tick labels. try to reduce  tick labels' font size, for example with adding `ticklabel style={font=\tiny},` to axis preamble. after than you can delete `zticklabel style = {yshift=0.1cm}`.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your remark. I know that it is a font size problem, but I would rather move a bit labels from the ticks than change the font size or image size. Is there no way to add a bit of space between labels without positionning them by hand?

Comment: as far as i know, only way to add more space around labels is use smaller fonts for labels or increase diagram size.

Answer (score 2):

You could rotate them.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath}
%
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %graphique      
        \begin{axis}[
            width=4 cm,
            height=4 cm,
            xmin=3,xmax=6,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.023,
            zmin=1,zmax=1.8,
            xlabel=x,
            ylabel=y,
            zlabel=z,
            zticklabel style = {yshift=0.1cm}, %to prevent it from colliding with xlabels
            xtick = {3,4,5,6},
            ytick ={0.006,0.012,0.017,0.023},
            yticklabels = {0.6,1.2,1.7,2.3},
            ztick ={1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8},
            scaled y ticks = false,
            yticklabel style={rotate=-30},
            view           = {30}{30},
            ]  

            \addplot3[fill=black!15,opacity=0.35,thick] (4,0,1) -- (4,0.023,1) -- (4,0.023,1.8) -- (4,0,1.8) -- cycle;

        \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is a cunning answer! Any hint as to why "1.2" and "1.7" seem closer to each other ? (they are touching a bit, while there is some space between "1.7" and "2.3")

Comment: @jeannej This is because `1.7-1.2=0.5<0.6=2.3-1.7`.